# Xml Namespace Prefix Normalizer

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces

I have XML that looks like this:

```
<ns1:TextXML xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/namespace/1" xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/namespace/2" xmlns:ns3="http://www.example.com/namespace/3">
    <n2:Child1 xmlns:n2="http://www.example.com/namespace/2">
        <n3:Child2 xmlns:n3="http://www.example.com/namespace/3">THIS IS CONTENT</n3:Child2>
    </n2:Child1>
</ns1:TextXML>
```

The following namespace prefixes map to the same underlining Namespace URI

ns2 and n2 => http://www.example.com/namespace/2

ns3 and n3 => http://www.example.com/namespace/3

Using C#, I'd like to convert the XML so that the Namespace Prefixes are all normalized and moved to the Root Element like this

```
<ns1:TextXML xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/namespace/1" xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/namespace/2" xmlns:ns3="http://www.example.com/namespace/3">
    <ns2:Child1>
        <ns3:Child2>THIS IS CONTENT</ns3:Child2>
    </ns2:Child1>
</ns1:TextXML>
```

I know that this code will move all the Namespace declarations to the top of the XML:

```
string strNewXML = @"<ns1:TextXML xmlns:ns1=""http://www.example.com/namespace/1"" xmlns:ns2=""http://www.example.com/namespace/2"" xmlns:ns3=""http://www.example.com/namespace/3"">
<ns2:Child1 xmlns:ns2=""http://www.example.com/namespace/2"">
<ns3:Child2 xmlns:ns3=""http://www.example.com/namespace/3"">THIS IS CONTENT</ns3:Child2>
</ns2:Child1>
</ns1:TextXML>";

var docNewXML = new XmlDocument();
docNewXML.LoadXml(strNewXML);
var docNewXMLns = new XmlNamespaceManager(docNewXML.NameTable);
docNewXMLns.AddNamespace("ns1", "http://www.example.com/namespace/1");
docNewXMLns.AddNamespace("ns2", "http://www.example.com/namespace/2");
docNewXMLns.AddNamespace("ns3", "http://www.example.com/namespace/3");

XmlWriterSettings xwsCfg = new XmlWriterSettings();
xwsCfg.Indent = false;
xwsCfg.NamespaceHandling = NamespaceHandling.OmitDuplicates; // This is doing the heavy lifting
xwsCfg.NewLineOnAttributes = false;
xwsCfg.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
xwsCfg.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

StringWriter swOutput = new EnvelopeFactory.EncodableStringWriter();
XmlWriter xwOut = XmlWriter.Create(swOutput, xwsCfg);
docNewXML.WriteTo(xwOut);
xwOut.Flush();
xwOut.Close();

var result = swOutput.ToString();
```

result =

```
<ns1:TextXML xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/namespace/1" xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/namespace/2" xmlns:ns3="http://www.example.com/namespace/3">
    <ns2:Child1>
        <ns3:Child2>THIS IS CONTENT</ns3:Child2>
    </ns2:Child1>
</ns1:TextXML>
```

However when I change strNewXML to:

```
<ns1:TextXML xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/namespace/1" xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/namespace/2" xmlns:ns3="http://www.example.com/namespace/3">
    <n2:Child1 xmlns:n2="http://www.example.com/namespace/2">
        <n3:Child2 xmlns:n3="http://www.example.com/namespace/3">THIS IS CONTENT</n3:Child2>
    </n2:Child1>
</ns1:TextXML>
```

Then the result =

```
<ns1:TextXML xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/namespace/1" xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/namespace/2" xmlns:ns3="http://www.example.com/namespace/3">
    <n2:Child1 xmlns:n2="http://www.example.com/namespace/2">
        <n3:Child2 xmlns:n3="http://www.example.com/namespace/3">THIS IS CONTENT</n3:Child2>
    </n2:Child1>
</ns1:TextXML>
```

And I am still left with duplicate Namespaces

Does anybody know of a good way accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: What is `EnvelopeFactory`?

Comment: `OmitDuplicates` only omits duplicate namespaces with duplicate prefixes.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want this as any proper xml parser is capable of parsing this content. I assume you want this for more human readability. you could create classes describing the message, then deserialize the message and serialize it again. This will remove alle namespaces and sets them only once. it i far fetched but it works.

Comment: @NetMage I did not realize I left that part of some custom code in... EncodableStringWriter is just a class that inherits StringWriter It has a default constructure that assigns Encoding.UTF8 to in internal field and then overrides the Encoding property of StringWriter (which is get only) so that it returns the encoding field. Is a workaround class because you cannot directly set the encoding of string writer and my application needs to output UTF-8 encoded xml

Comment: @martijn The use case for this issue is not about parsing or readability it is actually about bloat. My application deals in some vary large XML files that it receives from various third party systems. The XML we receive must conform to our agreed upon schemas but schemas don’t assigned a “correct” namespace prefix string and so the prefix string vary from user to user.

Comment: One of the things my application must do, is extract the payload elements from the incoming message and insert into another outgoing XML Envelope. The Parent xml envelope uses elements from the same namespace as what might be in the payload but the guest payload might use different prefix strings.

As a result, all the elements with the different prefix string all get the associated xmlns attribute applied which can increase the overall size of the final message by up to 25% in some cases.

Comment: @martijn I am a huge fan of using Serialization Classes to generate and work with XML messages. Unfortunately, the complexity of our xml standards and the sheer number of different message standards makes maintaining corresponding classes unrealistic for my application.

Comment: Can you use `XDocument` instead of `XmlDocument`?

Comment: @J.D.Green Prefixes can be anything as long as they are pointing to the same actual namespace defined in the message. any proper xml parser will understand that. so there is no need to try to set all the namespaces to specific prefixes. If you have an xml schema and your customers messages are valid against that schema you can use that schema to generate classes. there are tools like xsd.exe and xsd2code.exe that will generate classes from the schema for you. then you can deserialze and serialize without having to maintain a lot or huge classes.

Comment: @NetMage I don’t think I’ve used XDocument before, Let me give it a try and if I can get it to do what I want it to do, I’ll post the solution here

Comment: @martijn xsd2code.exe is my preferred utility for generating serialization classes from XML schemas. (Visual studio also lets you copy xml into the clipboard and then paste it as classes into a code file).

Comment: @martijn While all of the XML messages the application traffics in do have schemas, unfortunately, they are ever evolving and a update to the schema can’t also be dependent an update to the schema serialization classes and redeployment of the code in order to support. The application does not do much to the payload of the XML other than some basic xpath based validation and repackaging.
You are correct that a serialization / deserialization will likely resolve the namespace issue, it is just not a solution that is viable in my environment.

I do thank your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `XDocument` and LINQ to XML, you can adjust the attributes on the inner elements to remove the duplicated namespace declarations and the correct namespaces will be used automatically.

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(strNewXML);

var nsDecls = xdoc.Descendants()
                  .Attributes()
                  .Where(a => a.IsNamespaceDeclaration)
                  .GroupBy(a => a.Value)
                  .Select(ag => ag.DistinctBy(a => a.Name));
var wantedNSDecls = nsDecls.Select(ag => ag.First()).ToHashSet();

foreach (var xe in xdoc.Root.DescendantsAndSelf()) {
    var keepAttribs = xe.Attributes().Where(a => !a.IsNamespaceDeclaration || wantedNSDecls.Contains(a));
    xe.ReplaceAttributes(keepAttribs);
}
```

PS My answer uses an extension method, `DistinctBy`. You could also use `GroupBy().Select(.First())` in place of it. Here is the extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, TKey> keyFn, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer = null) {
    var seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>(comparer);
    foreach (var item in items)
        if (seenKeys.Add(keyFn(item)))
            yield return item;
}
```

For .Net FW < 4.7.2 or .Net Core < 2, you will need the `ToHashSet` extension method:

```
public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items) => new HashSet<T>(items); // including in .Net 4.7.2, .Net Core >2
public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, IEqualityComparer<T> cmp) => new HashSet<T>(items, cmp);
```

Comment: Dude! It works! Thank you so much. For some reason ToHashSet() did not show up as an extension method to Select so I had to use ToList() instead.. the resulting list is small so no big deal.

Comment: @J.D.Green Ah, `ToHashSet` is a recent addition to .Net - it is in .Net Framework 4.7.2 and .Net Core >= 2, I believe. I used to have my own extension method to do it instead - you could use `new HashSet(nsDecls.Select(...))` instead.

Comment: Ahh. that makes sense. My project is targeting 4.6.1.